# mapping network printers c#

Tags: c#, networking, printing

Is it possible to get network printer path using the following convention in C#

computername\printername

PrinterSettings.Installed printer gives out the printer name but not the path information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to get this information is to use the **IWshRuntimeLibrary** library (wshom.ocx).

```
WshNetwork network = new WshNetwork();
var printers = network.EnumPrinterConnections();
for (int i = 0; i < printers.Count(); i += 2)
{
     Console.WriteLine(printers.Item(i) + " \t" + printers.Item(i+1));
}
```

...But a more forward looking approach would be to use the information contained within Winspool's **PRINTER_INFO_2** structure which is returned from the **GetPrinter** method.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/PRINTER_INFO_2.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winspool.getprinter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This works for printer mapping. you need to make sure to add IWshRuntimeLibrary as a reference:

```
    using IWshRuntimeLibrary;
    private void MappPrinter()
    {
        WshNetwork oNetwork = new WshNetwork();
        oNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection("\\\\computername\\printername", "HPLJ6000","\\\\computername\\printername");
    }
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to get the network path to the printer, not how to add it as a local printer.

Comment: ooh, I just read the question title! BTW, I'm pretty sure using WMI queries the network path of the installed printers could be read. I will post the sample code here. sorry for wrong answer!